# For good SEO does my company's name need to be in text on each page or can a logo suffice?

Tags: seo

If I have a website that is for example MyTerrificBrand.com, then for good SEO do I need to have the words MyTerrificBrand (the name of the company) in the header as searchable text (on the top left, styled to be large and to stand out, of course) alongside the logo, or can I have purely an image containing MyTerrificBrand plus the logo?

The reason for my question is that our graphic designer styled the "MyTerrificBrand" in a unique way that we can't approximate through the stylesheet, so we'd prefer to use an image for MyTerrificBrand plus the logo.  But SEO is more important to us than a perfectly drawn company name.

Amazon.com and eBay for instance use an image on the top-left containing their names, not styled text. Is that okay for SEO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your company name doesn't have to be on each page in regular text. An image is fine as long  you use the `alt` attribute to put your company name, as it appears in the logo. That tells search engines, and users who have images disabled, what text that image contains. For search engines, it helps them understand that logo contains your company name and thus makes it relevant for searches for it. Users will still have something to click if the image is not loaded whether by design (images are turned off by the user) or error (poor internet connectivity).

Answer (score 0):

Naming your company on every page is not necessary unless you own a company that is very well known and your company name in itself is a potential part of the search strings your market targets are using. For example, if you own Coca-Cola, you would name your company through-out the site because although most of your visitors are actually looking for soda or soft drinks, etc, they may be looking for coca cola in particular. Now, this is not necessarily a must-do even for Coca Cola. The point of SEO is to be your website accessible  on the top pages of search engines, when visitors search for your **product** or **service** you sell, not your brand or company name. For example, in the above mentioned case, a search will look like this instead:

"where can I find cheap soda", or "soft drinks on sale", etc.

Your brand becomes important once you've made it to the first page and you are now competing with another 10 companies for that visitor's click. Basically, the guys who used the searches above received a result page with Coke, Pepsi, Ritz, and MyTerrificBrand....how do you think this will go for MyTerrificBrand?

If I were you, I'd just display your brand in any way you like, but focus more on your actual product and services to create indexable long tail keywords and inexable content.

Remember, as much as you think your brand kicks butt, in this day and economy, buyers are looking for the best bang for their buck. Focus on product.

Answer (score 0):

It would be very unusual not to have the company name in the text of each page.   I would recommend the following three locations:

- The alt text of the logo for accessibility to users that use screen readers.
- In the footer with a copyright notice.  (See: [When Do You Need a Copyright Notice on Websites](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/when-do-you-need-copyright-notice-websites-and-where-do-you-place-it.html))
- At the end of the title of each page.   Including your company name in page titles is important to establish brand recognition.   It can also increase click through rate (CTR) from the search results pages which helps SEO.

Answer (score -1):

Its fine if you just put the image but make an attribute of alt on the image.. For example: 
`IMG SRC="IMG/myterificbrand.PNG" alt="MyTerrificBrand"`